# typescript Enum reference error in runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I want to declare an enum in typescript

```js
// types/types.d.ts
declare enum SectionType {
    H1 = "H1",
    H2 = "H2",
    H3 = "H3",
    H4 = "H4",
    H5 = "H5",
    H6 = "H6",
    P = "P",
}

declare type Section = {
    type: SectionType
    text: string
}

declare type Page = {
    slug: string
    sections: Section[]
}

declare type Site = {
    slug: string
    pages: Page[]
}
```

but at runtime, when running this:

```
const defaultHomePage = {
    slug: 'home',
    sections: [
        {
            type: SectionType.H1,
            text: 'Hello World'
        }
    ]
}
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SectionType is not defined
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: How did you compile the scripts? Did you export an import the enum?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was in a declaration file (.d.ts) instead of a normal ts file. AFAIK I dont need to export types from a declaration file but I may be misunderstanding things

Comment: Ah. Yeah, [don't do that](https://lukasbehal.com/2017-05-22-enums-in-declaration-files/)

Comment: Is there then no way to globally declare enums in Typescript?

Comment: Sure there is, but to use them at runtime you can't have them only in a declaration file. See the duplicates for various solutions and workarounds.